# Keylogger: Save only deleted characters

Tags: operating-system, keylogger

This is a hypothetical coding question.
How can you make a program that can detect which characters are getting deleted throughout your OS and save them in text file?

I can only think of this approach (Pseudocode):

```
if (key detected && key != Delete Key):
    append("temporary.txt" with key)
else if( key == Delete Key):
    temp = read(temporary.txt)
    append("Log.txt" with temp.lastCharacter)
```

This approach only works when the user does not jump anywhere else in the text or changes the focus to another program. Also it does not account for highlighting and deleting text.

Is it possible to detect accurately what the user is deleting?

Answer (score 0):

If your program only intercepts keyboard input, then nope, there is no way to know where in a large text the user is inputting or deleting text.

You should ask yourself what you want to achieve, and if a keylogger is the right tool to achieve it, it is only so much a keylogger can do. Read [this info about the so called XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I want to have a text file that stores everything that I deleted. If a keylogger is not the right approach, what might be?
Is there even a solution for this problem?